# Set project directory as Workdir for Entrypoint in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, scala, apache-spark, docker, dockerfile

I have defined a Dockerfile with Spark installation. And I would like to load my application from the bash script defined as an entry point. However, this script should be implemented with parameters. This script is located in the project folder. The question is how to set this script as an entry point with defining the project directory as workdir?

My Dockerfile looks like this for now:

```
    FROM java:8

    ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.8
    ENV SBT_VERSION 1.1.1
    ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.2.0
    ENV SPARK_DIST spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.6
    ENV SPARK_ARCH $SPARK_DIST.tgz
    ARG SPARK_MASTER

    WORKDIR /opt

    # Install Scala
    RUN \
      cd /root && \
      curl -o scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
      tar -xf scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
      rm scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
      echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
      echo 'export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

    # Install SBT
    RUN \
      curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
      dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
      rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb


    # Install Spark
    RUN \
        cd /opt && \
        curl -o $SPARK_ARCH http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/$SPARK_ARCH && \
        tar xvfz $SPARK_ARCH && \
        rm $SPARK_ARCH && \
        echo 'export PATH=$SPARK_DIST/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc


    EXPOSE 9851 9852 4040 9092 9200 9300 5601 7474 7687 7473

    VOLUME /home/user/path/to/project /Demo

    WORKDIR /Demo

    ENTRYPOINT runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER
```

Comment: Have you tried using a volume ? Something like `VOLUME /path/to/project/root /Demo` followed by `WORKDIR /Demo` ?

Comment: @Aserre should I set an absolute path to my project? Because when I set the exact path like this `VOLUME ~/path/to/root  /Demo
WORKDIR /Demo` and try to run built image, my bash script can't be found

Comment: Yeah, docker won't understand `~` or relative path. You can use `$(pwd)` or absolute path though.

Comment: Also, you should probably write `ENTRYPOINT runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER` without the slash. With the slash, docker will look for the file `/rundemo.sh`. Witout, it will look for the file `$WORKDIR/rundemo.sh`

Comment: The error persists. The problem may lie in the path itself as it looks more like this: `/home/user/path/to/project /Demo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could do something like that :

```
...
EXPOSE 9851 9852 4040 9092 9200 9300 5601 7474 7687 7473

VOLUME /home/user/path/to/project /Demo

WORKDIR /Demo

ENTRYPOINT runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER
```

This will mount your local `/home/user/path/to/project` folder in the container's `/Demo`, then set `/Demo/runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER` as the entrypoint.

Note that if the script is standalone (i.e. doesn't have external dependencies in your project home directory), you can use `COPY` to add only the script to your container instead of mounting a full volume.

```
...
EXPOSE 9851 9852 4040 9092 9200 9300 5601 7474 7687 7473

COPY /home/user/path/to/project/runDemo.sh /Demo

WORKDIR /Demo

ENTRYPOINT runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER
```

Here is the documentation for [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) and [Dockerfile directives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format).

Comment: I have updated my Dockerfile in a question. When I  run it after building I get `/bin/sh: 1: runDemo.sh: not found`
`

Comment: @Cassie I am pretty sure it should be `./runDemo.sh` that's why you're getting command not found.

Comment: I tried that too and the only difference is that the error message looks like this: `/bin/sh: 1: ./runDemo.sh: not found`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the current directory will be `/Demo` and `runDemo.sh` is inside that folder, your entrypoint should look like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./runDemo.sh $SPARK_MASTER
```

Note the `.` this means current directory.

That has nothing to do with docker, it's just the standard way to execute programs/scripts which are not in the `$PATH` in Linux/Unix.

Comment: The problem is not in the entry point definition but in the definition of the volume for workdir from which to run a script.